# update query with inner join in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have written query to update two table with inner join:

```
function update($student_id,$data){
    $email=$data['Email'];
     $firstname=$data['FirstName'];

   $sql= "update users u
    INNER JOIN students s ON u.id= s.user_id
    SET u.Email='$email',
        s.Email='$email',
        u.FirstName='$firstname'
    WHERE s.id='$student_id'";
     $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result;
}
```

well I m not getting any error but i m not able to update table in database.

Comment: where is $sql ? echo your query and run through phpmyadmin

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma ohh that was mistake while writting here in SO

Comment: echo $sql; and run on phpmyadmin getting any row effected?

Comment: Your WHERE condition is out of "" and you are missing a ; , is that a mistake you did in your code or just here in StackOverflow ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma well, when i tried this with static data on phpmyadmin its working but when i tried like this with posted data $student_id its not working

Comment: echo $sql and paste it to question post?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
UPDATE u    
  SET u.Email='$email',
       s.Email='$email',
       u.FirstName='$firstname'  
from users u INNER JOIN  students ON s u.id= s.user_id  WHERE s.id='$student_id'
```